# Email warning showing even when field is empty using peer-invalid of tailwind in react. How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

So I'm making a sign up form for a website that uses react and tailwindcss. For email field, I wanna see if the email is valid or not. So i used the native tailwind **peer-{modifier}** for it.
Code:

```
<div className='flex w-full flex-col space-y-2'>
        <label htmlFor='email' className='text-sm text-gray-600'>
          Email address
        </label>
        <input
          type='email'
          id='email'
          autoComplete='email'
          required
          className='peer relative block w-full appearance-none rounded-md border border-gray-300 px-3 py-2 text-gray-900 placeholder-gray-500 focus:z-10 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 sm:text-sm disabled:bg-slate-50 disabled:text-slate-500 disabled:border-slate-200 disabled:shadow-none
                    invalid:border-pink-500 invalid:text-pink-600
                    focus:invalid:border-pink-500 focus:invalid:ring-pink-500'
          value={email}
          onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />
        <p className="mt-2 invisible peer-invalid:visible text-pink-600 text-sm">
            Please provide a valid email address.
        </p>
</div>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

it shows this error message even when there's nothing entered yet. How do i fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it shows at the start is because of `required` attribute. When `required` is set in a field, it means that this field must have some values. So at the start, your input field is in an invalid state -> the error message appears.

Here are some solutions

- Using React only: pretty simple (remember to remove peer in the `input` field)

```
{!isEmailValid(value) && <p className="mt-2 text-pink-600 text-sm">
    Please provide a valid email address.
</p>}
// ...
const isEmailValid = (email: string) => {
    if (email.length === 0) return true;
    // other checks here
    return false;
}
```

- Using Tailwind only: I have to use a little trick (learned from [Chris Coyier](https://css-tricks.com/form-validation-ux-html-css/#aa-sub-trick-testing-if-an-input-has-a-value-or-not)) to fix this (**you have to add placeholder to the `input` field**)

```
<input className="peer ..." ... placeholder="Your email address..." />
<p className="mt-2 invisible peer-placeholder-shown:!invisible peer-invalid:visible text-pink-600 text-sm">
    Please provide a valid email address.
</p>
```

In short, I use `peer-placeholder-shown` to hide the error message, but the specificity of `peer-placeholder-shown` is lower than that of 'peer-invalid' so I have to use the question mark to push its specificity. Here is the Tailwind [demo](https://play.tailwindcss.com/IuKWlIgxjD) if you need.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$v.user.email.$error` condition to avoid the error that is showing even if the fields are empty at starting.

```
<p class="mt-2 text-sm text-red-600" v-if="$v.user.email.$error">
  Email is required
</p>
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65151936/13680835